# calling a private sub from the filter workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call in a private sub from another folder in VBA.
[image]

The private sub is in the filter module.

Application.Run ("Forms.UserForm_Initialize")

I tried to use this line of code but it came up with run time error.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Application.Run, instead use Filter.Show or Call func_name